# How can I adjust the gridview of my customized calendar

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I've *been able to make a customized calendar that can hold events but I cant help but notice the "1" under the days of the calendar
[Here's the picture][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUppW.png

Here is the code for my customized calendar:

```
     package com.example.projecttweeta;

     import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
     import android.content.Context;
     import android.database.Cursor;
     import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
     import android.text.InputType;
     import android.util.AttributeSet;
     import android.view.LayoutInflater;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.widget.AdapterView;
     import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
     import android.widget.Button;
     import android.widget.EditText;
     import android.widget.GridView;
     import android.widget.ImageButton;
     import android.widget.LinearLayout;
     import android.widget.TextView;
     import android.widget.TimePicker;
     import android.widget.Toast;

     import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
     import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;

     import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
     import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout;

     import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
     import java.util.ArrayList;
     import java.util.Calendar;
     import java.util.Date;
     import java.util.List;
     import java.util.Locale;
     import java.util.TimeZone;

     import static android.icu.text.DateFormat.MONTH;
     import static android.icu.text.DateFormat.YEAR;




   public class CustomCalenderView extends LinearLayout {

// Created instances for the code to run...

ImageButton NextButton, PreviousButton;
TextView CurrentDate;
GridView gridView;
private DBOpenHelper dbOpenHelper;

public static final int MAX_CALENDER_DAYS = 42;
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
Context context;

SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
SimpleDateFormat monthFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM", Locale.ENGLISH);
SimpleDateFormat yearFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
SimpleDateFormat taskDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);

GridAdapter myGridAdapter;
AlertDialog alertDialog;
List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<>();
List<Tasks> tasksList = new ArrayList<>();


public CustomCalenderView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomCalenderView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
    InitializeLayout();
    setUpCalender();

    PreviousButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
            setUpCalender();
        }
    });

    NextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
            setUpCalender();
        }
    });


    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // an alert dialog; might change later...
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setCancelable(true);
            View addView = 
           LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.set_reminder_layout, null);
            EditText taskTitle = addView.findViewById(R.id.title_edit_text);
            EditText taskDescription = addView.findViewById(R.id.description_edit_text);
            TextView taskTime = addView.findViewById(R.id.time_edit_text_view);

            taskTime.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

            // Find a way to include settings or something around here

            Button saveTask = addView.findViewById(R.id.save_button);

            taskTime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int hours = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                    int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(addView.getContext(), 
           R.style.DatePickerTheme, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                            Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                            calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                            calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                            calendar1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
                            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
                            String plannedTime = sdf.format(calendar1.getTime());
                            CurrentDate.setText(plannedTime);

                        }
                    }, hours, minute, false);
                    timePickerDialog.show();
                }
            });
            String date = taskDateFormat.format(dates.get(position));
            String month = monthFormat.format(dates.get(position));
            String year = yearFormat.format(dates.get(position));

            saveTask.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    saveTaskEvent(taskTitle.getText().toString(), 
            taskDescription.getText().toString(), taskTime.getText().toString(), date, month, year);
                    setUpCalender();
                    alertDialog.dismiss();


                }
            });

            builder.setView(addView);
            alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }

    });


}

public CustomCalenderView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, Context 
 context1) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

private void saveTaskEvent(String title, String description, String time, String date, String Mmonth, String mYear) {
    dbOpenHelper = new DBOpenHelper(context);
    SQLiteDatabase database = dbOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    dbOpenHelper.SaveTask(title, description, time, date, Mmonth, mYear, database); // supposed to put database here but... meh
    dbOpenHelper.close();
    Toast.makeText(context, "Task saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}


private void InitializeLayout() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calender_layout, this);
    NextButton = view.findViewById(R.id.next_btn);
    PreviousButton = view.findViewById(R.id.prev_btn);
    CurrentDate = view.findViewById(R.id.current_date);
    gridView = view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);


}


private void setUpCalender() {
    String currentDate = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    CurrentDate.setText(currentDate);
    dates.clear();
    Calendar monthCalender = (Calendar) calendar.clone();
    monthCalender.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    int firstDayOfMonth = monthCalender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
    monthCalender.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -firstDayOfMonth);
    collectTasksPerMonth(monthFormat.format(calendar.getTime()), yearFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));

    while (dates.size() < MAX_CALENDER_DAYS) {
        dates.add(monthCalender.getTime());
        monthCalender.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    }

    myGridAdapter = new GridAdapter(context, dates, calendar, tasksList);
    gridView.setAdapter(myGridAdapter);


}



private void collectTasksPerMonth(String month, String year) {
    tasksList.clear();
    dbOpenHelper = new DBOpenHelper(context);
    SQLiteDatabase database = dbOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = dbOpenHelper.ReadTasksPerMonth(month, year, database);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBStructure.TITLE));
        String description = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBStructure.DESCRIPTION));
        String time = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBStructure.TIME));
        String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBStructure.DATE));
        String Mmonth = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBStructure.DMONTH));
        String mYear = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBStructure.DYEAR));
    //            Tasks tasks = new Tasks(title,description,time,date,month,year);
        Tasks maketask = new Tasks(title, description, time, date, Mmonth, mYear);
        tasksList.add(maketask);
    }
    cursor.close();
    dbOpenHelper.close();
  }


 }
```

And here is my grid adapter...

```
    package com.example.projecttweeta;

    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.GridLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;

     import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
   import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.List;
     import java.util.Locale;

  public class GridAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
List<Date> dates;
Calendar currentDate;
List<Tasks> tasks;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public GridAdapter(@NonNull Context context, List<Date> dates, Calendar currentDate, List<Tasks> tasks) {
    super(context, R.layout.single_cell_layout); // work on that after this...
    this.tasks = tasks;
    this.dates = dates;
    this.currentDate = currentDate;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}


@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    Date monthDate = dates.get(position);
    TextView tv;
    Calendar dateCalender = Calendar.getInstance();
    dateCalender.setTime(monthDate);
    int dayNo = dateCalender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int displayMonth = dateCalender.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    int displayYear = dateCalender.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int currentYear = currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int currentMonth = currentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;

    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_cell_layout, parent, false);


    }

    if (displayMonth == currentMonth && displayYear == currentYear) {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#60DDED"));
    } else {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }

    TextView day_number = view.findViewById(R.id.calender_day);
    TextView task_number = view.findViewById(R.id.task_id);
    day_number.setText(String.valueOf(dayNo));
    Calendar taskCalender = Calendar.getInstance();


    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    // SOLVED!!!!
    for (int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++) {
        taskCalender.setTime(convertStringToDate(tasks.get(i).getDATE()));
        if (dayNo == taskCalender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) && displayMonth == taskCalender.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1 && displayYear == taskCalender.get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
            arrayList.add(tasks.get(i).getTITLE());
            task_number.setText(arrayList.size() + " Tasks");
        }
    }


    return view;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return dates.size();
}


private Date convertStringToDate(String taskDate) {
    java.text.SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = format.parse(taskDate);
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return date;
}


@Override
public int getPosition(@Nullable Object item) {
    return dates.indexOf(item);
}


@Nullable
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return dates.get(position);
}
}
```

Please I'd need a response ; I'm on a deadline. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: What is your `R.layout.single_cell_layout`

Comment: Whoa thanks, man! Found the problem: I made the mistake of adding ` android:text = "1"` to my layout. I thought the problem came from my Java class